# Uncaught Syntax error.Unexpected Identifyer with Underscore

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

Hi there I am getting the above error and struggling to find where the problem lies.

Here is the code.

```
<%if(Validations!==null)%>
<%if(Validations.length)%>
<% _.each(Validations, function(validation){%>
<% _.each(ApplicationTemplateFields, function(applicationTemplateField){%>
<% if(applicationTemplateField.UniqueKey == validation.UniqueKey) {%>
<div class="form-group has-error">
    <label for="<%= applicationTemplateField.FieldName %>"><%= applicationTemplateField.FieldName %></label>
    <label class="control-label" for="inputError1"><%= validation.ValidationMessage %></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control inputs" id="inputError1" data-fieldkey="<%= applicationTemplateField.UniqueKey %>">
</div>
<%} else {%>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="<%= applicationTemplateField.FieldName %>"><%= applicationTemplateField.FieldName %></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control inputs" id="input<%= applicationTemplateField.Id %>" placeholder="Enter <%= applicationTemplateField.FieldName %>" data-fieldkey="<%= applicationTemplateField.UniqueKey %>">
</div>
<% } %>
<% }) %>
<% }) %>
<% } %>
<% } %>
```

Pointer perhaps as to where the problem could be.?

Answer (score 0):

Got it...silly Syntax error

```
<%if(Validations!==null)%>
<%if(Validations.length)%>
```

should be

```
<%if(Validations!==null){%>
<%if(Validations.length){%>
```